# iOS CIFilter of RAW Image Memory Issue (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

i am applying a CIFilter to a RAW image however I am facing some memory problems when I try to display it in an UIImageView.
I apply the CIFilter by using the following code:

```
CIFilter *rawshadow = [CIFilter filterWithImageURL:initialImageUrl options:@{kCIInputBoostShadowAmountKey: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.shadowsSlider.value],kCIInputScaleFactorKey: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1]}];
currentImage = rawshadow.outputImage;
```

And then I update the UIImageView by using the following:

```
-(void) UpdatePreview{
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextCacheIntermediates: [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kCIContextPriorityRequestLow:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]}];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:currentImage fromRect:[currentImage extent]];
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    [self.mainImageView setImage:img];
}
```

After running UpdatePreview the RAM spikes up to 2GB and crashes.
The raw image I am using is 6000x4000 and is around 24MB.
Is it too big or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you were not using CIFilter, it is *always* wrong to assign to an image view an image larger than needed for display. Your image view is not 6000x4000, so your image should not be. And in fact, *your* image is not 6000x4000: it is 12000x8000, or even 18000x12000, because you are converting from a CGImage to a UIImage incorrectly (you are using an implicit `scale` of 1, rather than setting the `scale` to your screen's resolution). No wonder you're crashing.

Process the original image at the needed size, or reduce the image size as part of the filter chain, so that the output image is the size actually needed for display in your interface. (And there is no need to pass through a CGImage on the way to a UIImage; you can render directly from a CIImage to a UIImage.)

Comment: Ok, processing the image at a lower scale works for displaying. But let's say I need to save a full scale version to camera roll, the app still crashes. How could I fix that?

Comment: Sorry, are you saying my answer did solve the problem for the question you originally asked?

Comment: It solved the problem of displaying it, but I can't save it full-size.

Comment: Maybe iOS just can't do that? But maybe it would depend on how you're saving. Try to debug so as to determine at exactly what point the crash occurs. Then I suggest you ask a new question showing the new saving code and the point where you crash and what the crash log says, and let's try to deal with it there. Thanks!

Comment: For example, if your plan is to save from the output image of the CIFilter directly to disk, you should not make a UIImage at all; just call CIContext's `writeJPEGRepresentation` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/1642218-writejpegrepresentation) to save the CIImage as image data directly to disk. That way, the full image data is never part of your app's memory.